How do I view summary() for a neural network?
If I have the entire model saved in HDF5 format, I can upload it like this:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import save_model, Sequential, load_model

my_model = keras.models.load_model('/content/my_checkpoint.h5')

and then I can watch summary() and see the model parameters
my_model.summary()

the same thing happens if the model is completely saved in the directory, as:
model.save('path/to/dir/for/model/')

the model will be a set of files:

I can also download the model from this directory and see summary()
model_2 = keras.models.load_model('path/to/dir/for/model/')
model_2.summary()

However, if the model is saved as weights in Checkpoint format and is a set of files:

How can I restore/load the model so that I can view its summary() ?
